# How do I check my entire library if any games have an update on Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

Often when I haven't played a Nintendo Switch game in a few months I'll find out there's an update just as I go to play. I know I can check if an individual game has an update via the options, but how do I check if any game in my library has an update without checking every game manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to check every game manually your best option is to enable the "Auto-Update Software" in the System section, because there's no other way to update a software.

I don't think there's a solution, also because the [How to Update Software on Nintendo Switch](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22767/%7E/how-to-update-software-on-nintendo-switch) support page only explains those methods.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize I had auto-update turned off.